# The lightbox can't be displayed when I use fancyBox3 just like demo code,why?

Tags: jquery, fancybox-3

The following code is based the demo code at http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#usage, I hope to display a lighbox for image, but the code don't work , why?

To: Rick, I have modified my code by your code, but it doesn't work yet,why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My page</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fancybox.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Your HTML content goes here -->


    <a href="bmp/logo.png" data-fancybox data-caption="My caption">
        <img src="bmp/logo.png" alt="" />
     </a>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**The Modified Code doesn't work too.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My page</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fancybox.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Your HTML content goes here -->


    <a href="bmp/logo.png" data-fancybox data-caption="My caption">
        <img src="bmp/logo.png" alt="" />
     </a>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
            // Options will go here
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to set the options probably

Comment: Do you get any errors in `console.log` ?

Comment: Try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uy5hjntv/

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing it..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
        // Options will go here
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! To: Rick, I have modified my code by your code, but it doesn't work yet,why?

Comment: you have to add some actual content.. `<img src="bmp/logo.png" alt="" />`. replace that with a simple "test" and it'll work.. https://jsfiddle.net/x91343ru/

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work yet !  Could you write a full sample code for me ? Thanks!

Comment: I provided a fiddle.. just replace the word "test" with your actual image..

Comment: Fiddle isn't full code, could you write code just like my code in Ask

Comment: use the exact same code you have in your modified code.. simply add an image named "logo.png" into this exact location of your website: `bmp/logo.png`. now test it out again..

Comment: Thanks! I test my code with VS Express 2012 at local just like http://localhost:55450/image.htm

Comment: Do you mean that I must upload my code to remote hosting to test ?

Answer (score 0):

What you always should do first is to open developer tools and check console for any message. There should be a clue. I guess you are not loading js and css files correctly - check if they exists and adjust file paths if needed.

btw, you can use fancyBox from CSDN, too -

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
```